# What does the nscannedObjectsAllPlans in MongoDb explain mean

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to examine a query and Im not sure what "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" and "nscannedAllPlans" is doing because I see that if I run a query directly off an indexed field "purchaseState"

I get the same results scanned items for 
"**nscannedObjects**", "**nscanned**", "**nscannedObjectsAllPlans**", and "**nscannedAllPlans**"

However once I added price greater than 400 into the query the
 **nscannedObjectsAllPlans** is now greater than the **nscannedObjects**
I wanted to know if  **nscannedObjectsAllPlans** is the total number of scanned objects that running a plan with the purchase_state index along with the purchase_state_Id index?
or is it just stating the Greater of the two index plan results??

I added an index to pruchase state 
then I added an index on purchase state and Id

db.toys.ensureIndex({"purchaseState" :  1})

db.toys.ensureIndex({"purchaseState" :  1, "_id" : 1})

```
            **db.toys.find({"purchaseState" : "NY"}).pretty().explain()**

               "cursor" : "BtreeCursor purchaseState_1",
               "isMultiKey" : false,
               "n" : 1596,
               "nscannedObjects" : 1596,
               "nscanned" : 1596,
               "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1596,
               "nscannedAllPlans" : 1596,
               "scanAndOrder" : false,
               "indexOnly" : false,
               "nYields" : 0,
               "nChunkSkips" : 0,
               "millis" : 3,
               "indexBounds" : {
                       "purchaseState" : [
                               [
                                       "NY",
                                       "NY"
                               ]
                       ]
               },
               "server" : "XXXXXXX:27017"

            **db.toys.find({"purchaseState" : "NY", "price": { $gt : 400 }}).pretty().explain()**

               "cursor" : "BtreeCursor purchaseState_1",
               "isMultiKey" : false,
               "n" : 1423,
               "nscannedObjects" : 1596,
               "nscanned" : 1596,
               "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1808,
               "nscannedAllPlans" : 1808,
               "scanAndOrder" : false,
               "indexOnly" : false,
               "nYields" : 0,
               "nChunkSkips" : 0,
               "millis" : 10,
               "indexBounds" : {
                       "purchaseState" : [
                               [
                                       "NY",
                                       "NY"
                               ]
                       ]
               },
               "server" : "XXXXXXX:27017"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB runs different available plans in parallel and pick the best one of it and remembers that plan for that kind of data set.  It also automatically valdiate the plan for every 1000 writes there after on that collection to make sure they have the right plan in for further similar query executions.

nscannedObjectsAllPlans means that when you are running a query and let us say, they go with two different plans, it shows that count.

There is no clear documentation available for nscannedObjectsAllPlans / nscannedAllPlans.  I have went through the [MongoDB course](https://education.10gen.com/dashboard) where it is not explained either, but the way it picks up the best plan, indirectly gives the answer for the nscannedAllPlans.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for documentation on this but guess there really isn't much yet.

Comment: @crackhaus You are welcome.  Glad, you find it helpful.  The product and the documentation is in its early stage, hope it will improve over the time.

Answer (score 2):

When MongoDB is executing a query, it may try executing several different plans in parallel to see which is best.  nscannedAllPlans is the sum of nscanned across all plans, and ditto for nscannedObjectsAllPlans/nscannedObjects.